# Firefox does not recogize my bind methods

Tags: javascript, dom-events

IE, Chrome, and Safari work. However Firefox gives an error on this method.  I'm trying to get the actual message as it disappeared. I will post it, but for now I can't hit <kbd>enter</kbd> on my forms.  Here is the method it pointed to:

13 is the <kbd>enter</kbd> key

```
function bind_enter_key(evt, callback)
{
    if(event.keyCode===13)
    {
        callback();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Call to `bind_enter_key` here:

```
set_onkeypress('signup_pass', function(event){return bind_enter_key(event, interface_signup);}); 
set_onkeypress('signin_pass', function(event){return bind_enter_key(event, interface_signin);});
```

Comment: C++, really?  Isn't this JavaScript?

Comment: How exactly are you binding the event handler? What are you binding it to?

Comment: Not much we can say until we see how the method is called, bound.... also, where does `event` come from? It's not defined anywhere. The fact that the method accepts a second parameter is also strange for an event handler. You definitely have to provide more information.

Comment: I added the calls in...it is called from an anonymous function which set the parameters....this works fine in IE, Chrome, and Safari...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
if(event.keyCode===13)
```

to

```
if(evt.keyCode===13)
```

and call the function with

```
bind_enter_key(event || window.event, interface_signup)
```

You named the parameter `evt` in your function signature, but you are not using it. It works in the other browsers because for some reason they provide the `event` object as `window.event` like IE is doing. But Firefox does not, hence `event` is `undefined` inside `bind_enter_key`.

Comment: @stack.user.0 - javascript doesn't "know", it works it out at run time. It just knows it has a varaible, you write an expression with the variable and if its value (which might be a string, number, Object, whatever) is appropriate for the expression, it returns a value (which might be a primitive or reference to an object). If not, you (probably) get an error. Read ECMA-262, it tells you how it works.